# Python 3 backward compatibility for print statement

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7

I just installed a python based library that claims to be compatible with python 2.7+.  However, when I go to the run the first sample in their readme I get the `SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'`.

Groan!

I suppose I can dial code back to use Python 2.7.  But before I go there, I wonder if there might exist some other widget that can be installed that perhaps the developers had access to that automatically allows the unparenthesized print statement to work without recoding the whole mess?

Comment: Is the syntax error in the sample code, or in the library itself? It might be that the library code is indeed forwards compatible, but they've not updated all the code in the documentation yet.

Comment: I'm a bit confused by this question. When the devs say 2.7+ they might not be including 3. They might more accurately mean 2.7.x. I assume you're using Python 3.X? There's also the possibility that they've updated their library to work with Python 3.X, but they haven't updated their sample programs. Which library is it?

Comment: You could try something like [this](https://docs.python.org/2/library/2to3.html) to automatically convert it. If it's just a few print statements it will probably work fine (haven't tried myself)

Comment: @bfris The only explanation that makes sense to me is yours.  2.7+ might mean any 2.x version > 2.7.  Although I could swear I read something else in their docs about using 3.4.

Comment: @Spencer this is the widget I was thinking of.  I'd come across it but forgotten its name.  But it's a translator, not what I was looking for which was some sort of interceptor that 'corrected' the code on the fly.

Comment: Whoa, sounds fancy! Never heard of anything like that, but it sounds... unclean. I'm not that advanced with python but depending on what your code looks like I suppose you could work out some kind of advanced try-catch in your __main__ block? I'd just rather tackle the problem. Even a little find-replace in your IDE could do the trick.

Comment: Yeah, I couldn't imagine such a thing working either, but thought maybe someone created it.  I don't know what's going on here.

Comment: Which library are you using? Some of us may already be using in on Python 3 with no issue. Or depending on the size of the library, it might not be that painful to fix it for your use.